# How to override component on specific slot

Tags: spartacus-storefront

i'm trying to make a banner component to use as SimpleBannerComponent, but i need to override only in a specific slot/section on homepage.
In another pages I will use the default component.

How can I do that?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to create a new CMS component only for that specific slot/section on homepage, because once you update a component, all its instances will also be updated everywhere.

Documentation on how to create and map a new component can be found on [Spartacus Documentation Site](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/creating-pages-and-components/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is using `OutletComponents`.

```
//...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [OutletComponent],
  //...,
  providers: [
    //...,
    provideOutlet({
      id: 'slotName',
      position: OutletPosition.BEFORE, // You can use 'REPLACE' and 'AFTER' too
      component: OutletComponent,
    }),
  ],
})
export class OutletModule {}
```

For more data you can see https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/eaef8c61b6d9477daf75bff9ac1b7eb4/b98af37456b2493e8fd5e733931c5cb4.html?q=outlet